# Construct a container without using STL

Tags: c++, templates, stl, containers

I want to implement a Container class, without using STL. Need advice on how to go about the implementation.

Much appreciated.

Comment: As it stands right now, this is clearly much too broad to answer. What sort of container do you want? What sort of interface do you want it to provide to its clients?

Comment: A simple container with basic functions to add/remove/view values, as of now. I've just not been able to find any implementation of a basic container that does not use STL.

Comment: I wrote a blog post about at least the beginnings of one some time ago: http://coderscentral.blogspot.com/2012/08/c-dynamic-arrays.html.

Comment: I'll go through it, thanks.